# Prevent top scroll after update state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Hi I have problem with **scroll to top page after every render**.
In  my Root component, when I get Array of objects items from **Redux Store**.
I filter mainArray on three subsArrays like : Hot, Favorite, Regular, then render each of them on specific route.
The filter func is running each time when mainArray is updated: like rating is rise and down or set favorite will be marked.
The question is, why react render each times when action is dispatching to redux store(I think redux causes this,I guess) and how I can prevent this.
Please give me a hint, I struggle with it for a while...

```
function Root() {
  const state = useSelector((state) => state);
  const { mainList: list } = state;

  const [regularList, setRegularList] = useState([]);
  const [hotList, setHotList] = useState([]);
  const [favoriteList, setFavoriteList] = useState([]);

const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleVote = (e) => {
    const currentId = Number(e.nativeEvent.path[3].id);
    const name = e.currentTarget.dataset.name;

    dispatch(listActions.vote(currentId, name));
  };

  const handleSetFave = (e) => {
    const currentId = Number(e.nativeEvent.path[3].id);
    dispatch(listActions.setFave(currentId));

const setArrays = (arr) => {
    const regularArr = arr.filter((meme) => meme.upvote - meme.downvote <= 5);
    const hotArr = arr.filter((meme) => meme.upvote - meme.downvote > 5);
    const favoriteArr = arr.filter((meme) => meme.favorite);

    setRegularList([...regularArr]);
    setHotList([...hotArr]);
    setFavoriteList([...favoriteArr]);
};

useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.getItem("mainList") &&
      dispatch(
        listActions.setMainList(
          JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("mainList"))
        )
      );
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setArrays(list);
    list.length > 0 &&
      window.localStorage.setItem("mainList", JSON.stringify(list));
  }, [list]);

return (
    <div className={styles.App}>
      <Router>
        <Navigation />
        <Route path="/" component={FormView} exact />
        <Route
          path="/regular"
          component={() => (
            <MemesView
              list={regularList}
              handleVote={handleVote}
              handleSetFave={handleSetFave}
            />
          )}
        />
        <Route
          path="/hot"
          component={() => (
            <MemesView
              list={hotList}
              handleVote={handleVote}
              handleSetFave={handleSetFave}
            />
          )}
        />
        <Route
          path="/favorite"
          component={() => (
            <MemesView
              list={favoriteList}
              handleVote={handleVote}
              handleSetFave={handleSetFave}
            />
          )}
        />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );

  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why react render each times when action is dispatching to redux store

Because you are subscribing to the whole redux state (by using `useSelector((state) => state);`), remember that each time an action is dispatched, redux computes a new state.

So you should not write `const state = useSelector(state => state);` otherwise your component will be rerendered each time an action is dispatched. Instead you must select the part of the state you are interested in.

I can deduce from your code you want to be notified every time there is a change on the `mainList`, so you can write :

`const list = useSelector(state => state.mainList);`

You can get more info by reading the [documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#performance)

> by default useSelector() will do a reference equality comparison of the selected value when running the selector function after an action is dispatched, and will only cause the component to re-render if the selected value changed

Basically, the `scroll to top page` you are experiencing might also comes from a bad use of the `Route` component.

Try to use this

```
<Route path="/regular">
  <MemesView
    list={regularList}
    handleVote={handleVote}
    handleSetFave={handleSetFave}
  />
</Route>
```

instead of

```
<Route path="/regular"
       component={() => (
         <MemesView
           list={regularList}
           handleVote={handleVote}
           handleSetFave={handleSetFave}
         />
       )}
/>
```

Don't forget to also update `/hot` and `/favorite` routes.

You can read from the [react router documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component)

> When you use component (instead of render or children, below) the router uses React.createElement to create a new React element from the given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the component prop, you would create a new component every render. This results in the existing component unmounting and the new component mounting instead of just updating the existing component. When using an inline function for inline rendering, use the render or the children prop (below).

Comment: thanks for answer, It makes sense, but after correct that line of code, React still render each time when I make dispatch action.... any Idea ??

Comment: strange, does the action you dispatched update the `mainList` in your redux state ?

Comment: Yes, I map mainList in store, check each item by Id, then get proper item and update... change amount of votes or switch is favrotie true/false...
```
 case types.SET_FAVE:
      return {
        ...state,
        mainList: [
          ...state.mainList.map((item) => {
            if (item.id !== action.currentId) {
              return item;
            }

            return {
              ...item,
              ...(item.favorite = !item.favorite),
            };
          }),
        ],
      };
```
peace of "setFav" reducer action.
Is it fine ??

Comment: that's normal you have a rerender, because you are modiying the `mainList` array. So the behavior is nomal, you cannot prevent from rerendering otherwise the view will not be in sync with the `mainList` variable

Comment: Yeahh, I guess so. but why after render browser scroll top viewport ? To prevent that I should use eventListener ? Seems strange....

Comment: I suspect, it happens because of this `component={() => (...)` when declaring the `Route` component. I edited my answer to show you how to fix it

Comment: That was very helpfull, thanks a lot... I've searched over whole network about solution this problem.

Comment: it's often just necessary to read carefully the documentation about the libs you are using in your project to understand how it really works and how it should be used